# Enzyme still finding element that should be hidden by conditional rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have an app that renders a simple counter, which I am using to learn Jest and Enzyme. I want there to be shown an error message if the user tries to decrement the counter below 0. When a user sees the error and increments the counter above 0, I want the error message to be hidden. This works perfectly when I run the app but Enzyme seems to keep the part of the dom the error message is in, even though the counter is incremented.

#### This is my App component

```
function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
  const [showError, setShowError] = useState(false)

  const decrementCounter = () => {
    if(counter > 0) {
      setCounter(counter - 1)
    } else {
      setShowError(true)
    }
  }

  const incrementCounter = () => {
    if(showError) {
      setShowError(false)
    }

    setCounter(counter + 1)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App" data-test="component-app">
      <h1 data-test='counter-display'>The counter is <span data-test='count'>{counter}</span></h1>
      {showError ? <h3 style={{color: 'red'}} data-test='below-zero-error-message'>Can not go below 0</h3> : ''}
      <button onClick={incrementCounter} data-test='increment-button'>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={decrementCounter} data-test='decrement-button'>Decrement</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### This is my test and some functions used within it

```
const setup = () => shallow(<App />)
const findByTestAttr = (wrapper, val) => wrapper.find(`[data-test='${val}']`)

test('error message disappears when counter larger than 0', () => {
    const wrapper = setup()
    const decrementButton = findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'decrement-button')
    const incrementButton = findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'increment-button')
    decrementButton.simulate('click')
    let errorMessage = findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'below-zero-error-message')
    expect(errorMessage.length).toBe(1)
    incrementButton.simulate('click')
    errorMessage = findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'below-zero-error-message')
    expect(errorMessage.length).toBe(0)
})
```

When I run the tests I get this error, indicating that the error message is still in the dom even after I have incremented the counter.

```
    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 0
    Received: 1

      85 |     incrementButton.simulate('click')
      86 |     errorMessage = findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'below-zero-error-message')
    > 87 |     expect(errorMessage.length).toBe(0)
         |                                 ^
      88 | })
```

When I try to debug this with Enzyme the dom still includes the error message code even though the counter is clearly incremented.

```
    <div className="App" data-test="component-app">
      <h1 data-test="counter-display">
        The counter is
        <span data-test="count">
          1
        </span>
      </h1>
      <h3 style={{...}} data-test="below-zero-error-message">
        Can not go below 0
      </h3>
      <button onClick={[Function: incrementCounter]} data-test="increment-button">
        Increment
      </button>
      <button onClick={[Function: decrementCounter]} data-test="decrement-button">
        Decrement
      </button>
    </div>
```

When running the app and watching the dom in Chrome the part which includes the error message is removed once I increment the counter above 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way,

```
const setup = () => shallow(<App />);
const findByTestAttr = (wrapper, val) => wrapper.find(`[data-test='${val}']`);

test('error message disappears when counter larger than 0', () => {
    const wrapper = setup();
    
    //Decrement opration
    const decrementButton = findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'decrement-button');
    decrementButton.simulate('click');
    let errorMessage = findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'below-zero-error-message');
    console.log('Error ==>',wrapper.debug());
    expect(errorMessage.length).toBe(1);

    // Increment Operation
    const incrementButton = findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'increment-button');
    incrementButton.simulate('click');
    console.log('No error ==>',wrapper.debug());
    errorMessage = findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'below-zero-error-message');
    expect(errorMessage.length).toBe(0);
});
```

Let me know if you are facing any issues.

Comment: Works perfectly! Any idea why I can't get the increment button as early as I did?